# AWS X-RAY [Error] Sending segment batch failed with: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, distributed-tracing, x-ray

I'm using X-Ray Daemon with Fargate. Unfortunately in the logs of the daemon I see errors like:

> [Error] Sending segment batch failed with: NoCredentialProviders: no
> valid providers in chain. Deprecated. For verbose messaging see
> aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors Warn]  Delaying sending of
> additional batches by 0 seconds

AWS X-Ray works with IAM: permission: AWSXrayFullAccess

I already checked:

- https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-xray-fargate
- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/xray/latest/devguide/xray-guide.pdf

```
{
 "name" : "xray-daemon",
 "image" : "amazon/aws-xray-daemon",
 "user" : "1337",
 "essential" : true,
 "cpu" : "32",
 "memoryReservation" : "256",
 "portMappings" : [
 {
 "containerPort" : 2000,
 "protocol" : "udp"
 }
 ]
 }
 ],
 "requiresCompatibilities" : [ "FARGATE" ],
 "taskRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ecsTaskRole",
 "executionRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
 "networkMode" : "awsvpc"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check you role permissions role, I used the same for execution & taskRoleArn. my role contained these policies

- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
- arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXRayFullAccess

and also check trust relationships for role. my used:

- ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
- ecs.amazonaws.com
- c2.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my version of the x-ray deamon was old.

Follow this as guidance to update your x-ray deamon if it is running on ECS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html

Answer (score 0):

XRay daemon is missing credentials needed to authenticate with XRay server. You can pass credentials to XRay daemon in several ways, but the most common are:

1. through environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
2. through ~/.aws/credentials file (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

I'm guessing option 1 will be easier with fargate.

Of course you need to generate the key in IAM, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html

The user you'll create the access key for will need to have permissions to use XRay (AWSXrayFullAccess should do).

Comment: Please, note that passing AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is not needed and is a security flaw.
The best practice is assigning the right permissions to the role of task/service/EC2 Instance

Answer (score 0):

**option 1:**
As Lukasz said, All you want to do is to pass environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) during container creation.

and about execution role you shouldn't worry about it, recently AWS added the below policies by default to task execution role

- AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess
- AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
- systems-manager-parameters

[image: you can pass environment variables like below]

once you get ***[Info] Successfully sent batch of 1 segments (0.003 seconds)*** log in your task cloud watch just check the service map tab in X-Ray and you will find the graph

**Option 2:**
you may try using the old version (amazon/aws-xray-daemon:1)